# Launch non-blocking process from powershell

Tags: git, powershell, asynchronous, nonblocking

I'm writing a powershell script that needs to push code to several git repositories simultaneously?

Here's the script I have thus far:

```
param(
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$repoPath,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [array]$remoteRepos
)

pushd $repoPath
$remoteRepos | % { 
    #Want to exexcute this without blocking
    & git push $_ master --fore -v 
}
popd
```

Here's how I execute the script:

```
gitdeploy.ps1 -repoPath c:\code\myrepo -remoteRepos repo1,repo2
```

How to I execute the `& git push $_ master --fore -v` in a way that is non-blocking?

**SOLUTION**

Thanks to @Jamey for the solution. I wound executing this command:

```
Start-Process "cmd.exe" "/c git push $_ master --force -v"
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can also use start-process to run each push in an additional command window.

```
start-process -FilePath "git" -ArgumentList ("push", $_,  "master", "--fore", "-v")
```

Answer (score 3):

Micah, you can use start-job to run it in background - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347692.aspx

Answer (score 0):

How about `start git "push $_ master --force -v"`